# Applescript to send an email with signature

Tags: applescript

I am trying to send an email using Apple script. Everything works fine even email is sent to the address used in the script. My problem is I am unable to add the signature in the email content. Here is the code

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theSubject to "Subject if the testing email" -- the subject
    set theContent to "Body of the email goes here" -- the content
    set theAddress to "test123@gmail.com" -- the receiver address
    set theSignatureName to "Charu" -- the signature name


    set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, visible:true}
    tell msg to make new to recipient at end of every to recipient with properties {address:theAddress}

    set message signature of msg to signature theSignatureName
    send msg
end tell
```

When I try to run this I receive an error alert that says `Mail got an error: AppleEvent handler failed.`
I am not sure how to set the signature.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking back on previous threads (like [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329081/adding-a-signature-to-automator-email)), it seems that, with High Sierra and above, adding a signature using `message signature` does not work anymore. Your best bet is to just append your signature to `theContent`.

Comment: Thanks, This is what I was thinking to include the signature in the content. I thought there must be some fix for the same. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

For my macOS Monterey (12.6.6) Mail.app version 16.0 the following works:

```applescript
tell application "Mail"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"mySubject", content:"myContent", message signature:(signature named "mySig")}
    activate
end tell
```